# How to skip/exit from bower prompt asking for angular resolution version

Tags: angularjs, bower-install

I tried to install another package which got interrupted with following prompt asking for which version to use. Is there proper way to skip the installation instead of force stopping process using CTRL+C ? 
Thanks for any suggestion.

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
    1) angular#1.4.9 which resolved to 1.4.9 and is required by angular-mocks#1.4.9
    2) angular#>=1.2.26 <1.6 which resolved to 1.5.0 and is required by angular-translate#2.9.2, angular-translate#2.11.0, angular-translate#2.11.0
    3) angular#1.5.0 which resolved to 1.5.0 and is required by angular-cookies#1.5.0
    4) angular#^1.2.9 which resolved to 1.5.0 and is required by angular-loading-bar#0.9.0
    5) angular#>=1.4.0 which resolved to 1.5.0 and is required by angular-bootstrap#1.2.5
    6) angular#1.5.2 which resolved to 1.5.2 and is required by angular-mocks#1.5.2
    7) angular#^1.0.8 which resolved to 1.5.2 and is required by angular-ui-router#0.2.18
    8) angular#~1.5.2 which resolved to 1.5.2 and is required by angular-seed
    9) angular#>=1.3.x which resolved to 1.5.2 and is required by satellizer#0.14.0

Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
```

Answer (score 0):

`bower help` install is your friend... `bower install --force-latest` is probably your best bet

for no errors maybe try:

```
-q, --quiet             Only output important information
-s, --silent            Do not output anything, besides errors
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @Dr Jones, but I don't want to proceed with that installation, so no question of --force-latest also, just need to fail and exit with installation.

Comment: Maybe try:     -q, --quiet             Only output important information or/and   -s, --silent            Do not output anything, besides errors

Comment: But these options are not for skip or exit, rather for not prompting and continuing. What I need is - to skip or exit that installation if such thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide resolutions for your dependencies :

```
   {
      "name": "myapp",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "dependencies": {
        "angular": "~1.3.x"
          },
      "resolutions": {
        "angular": "~1.3.x"
      }
    }
```

this will force bower to install provided version.